# xcode freetype ld symbols not found for architecture x86_64

Tags: xcode, macos, freetype2

I add freetype to my multiplatform framework. Same code works fine on windows, but I'm unable to compile it on Mac OS X. I don't use freetype libraries and I compile everything from source code. My main project is written with C++. No matter what I try I always get some sort of errors regarding ftgzip file which is included in project settings.
Here's how the error looks like:
[image]

I'm running out of options and don't know what to try else. Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT:**
Atleast on firefox press right mouse button and view image, to see original resolution image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide those symbols in your code:

```
int z_verbose = 0;

void z_error(/* should be const */char* message)
{
    log_somewhere_or_ignore(message);
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't these already be defined in source files?
There is `extern int z_verbose;` and `extern void z_error OF((char *m));` defined in **zutil.h**. I don't quite understand the meaning of OFF near z_error, but Visual studio didn't complained about missing z_error. Any suggestions where should I put your code?

Comment: @SMGhost Note that those symbols are only used if `DEBUG` is defined, which might not be happening using VS (shrug - you tell me). Also I cannot tell you where to put those symbols as I don't know your code; perhaps create a new `.cpp` file for them?

Comment: @SMGhost Also note that I don't see any `extern "C"` statements in that header file which means you will get linkage errors anyway due to name mangling (due to mixing C and C++).  This will complicate things as well.

Comment: I just opened that damn ftgzip.c file added what you suggested and to my surprise it works now :O Big thanks :)